# returning a logical vector the same size as vector your checking

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of 6500 x 3000, called deal_matrix. I have a logical vector called active_deals 6500 x 1. Lastly I have another vector called country_codes which is 6500 x 1.

```
 active_deals = isnan(deal_matrix(:, 1));

 cty = 42                                           % 42 is the code for the US
 cty_active = zeros(6500, 1);
 cty_active = active_deals(country_codes == cty, 1);
```

currently cty_active will be a 3200 x 1 vector, which is correct in that there are 3200 active US deals. However I would like a 6500 x 1 vector returned for calculations later on.

Please see a brief example below,

```
  country_codes
  42
  51
  42
  42
  30
  33
  65
```

based on cty = 42 the logical vector I would like return is the same size as country_codes and should look like below,

```
  result vec
  1
  0
  1
  1
  0
  0
  0
```

Comment: `cty_active = zeros(6500, 1); cty_active(country_codes == cty) = active_deals(country_codes == cty);`?

Comment: yep correct as always! :-)